# Is google pays for each time the user navigate and new ads appear?

Tags: google, google-adsense, advertising

If I have mobile app and google ads in each page. 
(according to pay per view method) 
Is google pays for each time the user navigate and new ads appear?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it all depends on weather your being paid on a CPC (cost per click) basis or a CPM (cost per 1000 views) basis.

With CPC your paid each time your ad is clicked on, if its not clicked you dont get paid.

With CPM your paid for each 1000 impressions (views of your ad), so each time a new page loads it would also call for a new ad, if you had only 1 ad per page you'd generate 1 impression for each page load. If you had 2 ads per page you'd generate 2 impressions per page ect ect

for more info have a look at [this article](http://webanalysis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/cost-of-advertising-cpm-ecpm-and-cpc.html)